# Failing to Start neo4j 2.3.2

Tags: neo4j

> Starting neo4j 2.3.2 failed: Address localhost:7474 is already in use, cannot bind to it.

How to solve this problem?
I am not able to start neo4j server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting Neo4j failed: Address localhost:7474 is already in use, cannot bind to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797281/starting-neo4j-failed-address-localhost7474-is-already-in-use-cannot-bind-to)

Answer (score 0):

It is already running and thus stopping the new instance from binding to port 7474 on localhost. Stop the running instance and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, it is already started. In neo4j, like in may databases you need:

1. A server
2. A client

You already have the server ready. To work with a client just open your browser and type

```
localhost:7474/
```

which is the browser client. Enjoy it!