# Starting Neo4j failed: Address localhost:7474 is already in use, cannot bind to it on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, neo4j

I'm trying to install a neo4j server on my localhost (mac osx - El-capitan)  and i'm getting this error -

> Starting Neo4j failed: Address localhost:7474 is already in use,
>   cannot bind to it.

I tried to stop the port from running and then install it throw the neo4j install app, but it still give this error

When i try to start the neo4j server it gives me this error :

> ./usr/local/bin/neo4j: line 229: [: too many arguments

Comment: how did you install Neo4j ? with homebrew?

Comment: Just tried it, works for me. Do you have an unusual shell?

Comment: the latest version (try brew update) has only 2 lines in that shell script

Comment: I'm getting this error on a fresh homebrew installation.  Conflicts with port 1337.

Answer (score 5):

Try to kill your java processes :

```
sudo killall -9 java
```

Then restart your neo4j server :

```
./bin/neo4j restart
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I tried to kill all process running on :7474 but it still gives me this error.

When i do restart or start neo4j it give me this : 
./usr/local/bin/neo4j: line 229: [: too many arguments

Answer (score 0):

Same problem using Win 10, I had to turn off https-support
in `neo4j-server.properties`, i.e.

```
\# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to install anything. Just download the linux tar.gz package, uncompress it and use the terminal to run the command ‘./bin/neo4j console’ to run it in console mode.  You can start it in background too but based on your question, it sounds like this is just a dev machine.