# I deployed neo4j twice and I can't start neo4j now because 7474 port-binding

Tags: neo4j

First,I used neo4j-enterprise-3.1.0-M13-beta3 and now i use neo4j-enterprise-3.0.7 version. But i can't start the neo4j server because the 7474 port-binding and the neo4j.log showing 'ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: At least one of the addresses 0.0.0.0:7474 or localhost:7474 is already in use, cannot bind to it.'.
The neo4j server in version of neo4j-enterprise-3.1.0-M13-beta3 is stopped and
I use command line 'netstat -anp|grep 7474', 7474 is not used;
I change the port to 7475 and the neo4j server will start; Who can help me to unbind the 7474 port,and I will feel grateful,thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting Neo4j failed: Address localhost:7474 is already in use, cannot bind to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797281/starting-neo4j-failed-address-localhost7474-is-already-in-use-cannot-bind-to)

Comment: The only way to "unbind" is to find and kill the server instance that is using that port.